# Optimize SQL query on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have an SQL query on tables having a lot of rows. So this query runs for a very long time. How can I optimize this query?
These tables already have indexes on id and friend_id

```
SELECT u.id, u.first, u.last, 
  group_concat(u2.first, " " , u2.last) MyFriends 
  FROM Users u
  INNER JOIN Friends f ON f.user_id = u.id 
  INNER JOIN Users u2 ON u2.id = f.friend_id
  GROUP BY u.id;
```

These are the table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE Users ( 
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  first varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
  last varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
  city varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
  country varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
  Age tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  KEY users_idx_id (id)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE Friends ( 
  user_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  friend_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  KEY idx_friends (friend_id)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: you have to provide us the execution plan , and maybe the index definitions

Comment: also create an index on user_id in friends table.

Comment: @eshirvana I don't know how to provide an execution plan.

Comment: There are indexes for id in Users and friend_id in Friends

Comment: @Max study this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: the link  belongs to dba but still fits https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions

Comment: @RahulBiswas - In this situation, single-column indexes are not nearly as good as composite indexes; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A many-to-many mapping table (`Friends`) needs improved indexes.  Drop all the  indexes you have now and add

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, friend_id),
INDEX(friend_id, user_id)
```

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

`Age` is a moving target.  Think about a better way to store that.

There are about 6 countries with names longer than 20.  "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" is 32.

As for cities, 'Poselok Uchebnogo Khozyaystva Srednego Professionalno-Tekhnicheskoye Uchilishche Nomer Odin' is 91 chars.

```
ALTER TABLE Friends
    DROP INDEX idx_friends,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(user_id, friend_id),
    ADD INDEX(friend_id, user_id);
```

Every table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
ALTER TABLE Users
    DROP INDEX users_idx_id,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
```

Read about `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

The "execution plan" can be had by running `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  However it won't provide many clues *in this case*.

Comment: So is that the only change I need to do?

Comment: what is the command to add them?

Comment: @Max - I feel certain that it will speed up that query.  If it fails to satisfy enough, then provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  Also specify about how many rows there are in the tables.  (There are many less-common things that could be causing performance problems.)

Comment: @Max - I must see the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I can also specify how to drop the existing indexes.

Comment: @Max - I added a bunch.